# I need to setup VPN on Cisco 5505 PIX firewall with AD authentication!

Tags: cisco, cisco-vpn

I need to setup VPN on Cisco 5505 PIX firewall, when the user uses the vpn I need it to have domain authentication through active dirctory. How do I do this through ADSM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this chapter](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa71/asdm51/selected_procedures/asdmldap.html#wp1032888) on cisco.com.